# How to remove gap between border of website and image?

Tags: html, css

How to remove this gap between left and right borders? I need a pic be 100% of browser window.

[image]

```css
img.test {
  display: block;
  outline: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<img class="test" src="/img/back_1.jpg">
```

What I'm trying to do is to put a few pics in a row and I want them to look like a background like om this website: http://zhumusic.com

Comment: Have you removed the margin and padding from the `body` and `html` elements?

Comment: Some plaster should fix that gap :)  If you look at that site the `body` has `margin: 0;` applied, if you remove it (using dev tools in your browser F12) you can see that gap appear (when you also remove the background color)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting this in your CSS file:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried to put a `padding: 0;` because I thought that padding makes a gap between body border and content, but it didn't work. Don't understand why margin works.

Comment: @Lbovsky `body` is nested inside the `html` element so the margin is between those two elements